# Why do some airplanes fly at a very low speed (like this one) at a speed of 433 km/h (234 knots) at a whopping high altitude of 26,500 ft?

Tags: altitude, airplane

[image: **enter image description here**]

Okay. So I'am just having a doubt on this flight (BA359) flying from Lyon, France en-route to London Heathrow. It is flying at a way low speed of 433 km/h (234 knots) in which i think is a bit weird. It is quite far from London Heathrow before landing. But come on, the head wind is not way too much. I mean if it is way too much, the airplane will fly at TAS 700 km/h ( GS 950 km/h) corrected for a 250 km/h head wind/jet stream.

Or maybe there is an altitude restriction or instruction to fly at holding speed to finally hold at Biggin or Ockham holding stacks due to heavy inboud traffic? I'am just curious.

Comment: Ground speed is not the same as airspeed.  That plane may be facing a strong headwind.

Comment: Was the airplane climbing?

Answer (score 3):

433km/h seems really low, but keep in mind that flightradar is far from perfect. It is not uncommon that altitude, speed or position are far off, and sometimes, you see sudden jumps to more correct values when flight radar gets new data.

You can also check other sites like flightaware for particular fligt numbers, where you get a graph of altitude and speed, and can easily play back a given flight.

You didn't post a flight date, but the flights of the last few days have a speed of 600-700km/h at that position. This is below cruise speed, but the aircraft already start to reduce altitude and speed when leaving France.